# Snap vertices to grid on some objects in my model is broken. How can I fix them

Tags: modeling

I am working in blender 2.91.2 and I have a model that I want to snap its vertices to the grid want to make it ready for pixel art textures.

The character is made up of blocky objects and some of them have vertices that properly snap to the grid, but most of them snap to seemingly random positions if at all.

Take for example, the head and the neck here, the head's vertices snapped into position correctly, but in this screenshot, the only place the selected face on the neck will snap to that is remotely close to being flush with the head is here. It is like it is on some completely different grid. But when I drag it around with ctrl held, it doesn't even snap for most of the space that I drag it through.

Any ideas what is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transform in the screenshot is not set to “Increment + Snap to grid,” but rather “Snap to edge.” Change this and see if it works right.

Comment: I can't believe how long I spent pressing buttons in the window without noticing that haha. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristopherMorgan that’s happened to me sometimes 